# Why my serializer field does not show up?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Right now i have no problem with showing the output of the fields.But somehow i can't see the output of postlikes_set in json output. I don't get any error or something,i just can't see it. I don't know why. Does anybody know the issue? Here are my codes.

**Model**

```
class Article(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='articles')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class LikePostModel(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='postlikes',null=True)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**Serializer**

```
class LikePostViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = LikePostModel
        fields = ('id',"author","article")

class ArticleViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images_set = ArticleImageViewSerializer(source='images',required=False,many=True)
    comments_set = CommentViewSerializer(source='comments',required=False,many=True)
    postlikes_set = LikePostViewSerializer(source='postlikes',required=False,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id','caption','images_set','comments_set','postlikes_set')

    def create(self, validated_data):
     return Article.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

**Output**

```
[
    {
        "id": "092e929f-c845-403d-8373-84c745140c11",
        "caption": "caption",
        "images_set": [],
        "comments_set": []
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you explain ```source='postlikes'``` ? It seems like you're trying to access one field when you should refer to the model. Also you don't need to override the create() method if you don't change anything to it.

Comment: 'postlikes' have the same efficiency with 'comments'. When i remove 'comments' comments don't show up. create() method is the least priority right now.

Comment: Can you add the Article model ?

Comment: added it.You can take a look at it.

Comment: Can you please take a look at my answer and see if this solves your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access a field of your LikePostModel when your serializer model is Article. The difference with 'comments' is that it refers to a field of your Article model.

Now, i don't know exactly the JSON you're expecting but this will output the author (aka  postlikes) field of your LikePostModel inside its serializer.

```py
#models.py
class LikePostModel(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='postlikes',null=True)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='postlikes_set')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

# serializers.py
class LikePostViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = LikePostModel
        fields = ('id',"author","article")

class ArticleViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images_set = ArticleImageViewSerializer(source='images',required=False,many=True)
    comments_set = CommentViewSerializer(source='comments',required=False,many=True)
    postlikes_set = LikePostViewSerializer(required=False,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id','caption','images_set','comments_set','postlikes_set')

    def create(self, validated_data):
     return Article.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: Uh, i tried that out before.Still not working.

Comment: I changed article field of LikePostModel in your models.py. Can you look at it ?

Comment: No problem, always think about what model is your serializer about, and when you want to use reverse relations, best practise is to set a related_name in your ForeignKey object.

Comment: I already take caution looking for related_name,but setting source name in serializers always worked out. Guess it needed extra caution.